# Database connection parameters via environmental variables

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2, configuration, deployment

Currently working on the deployment of a Magento 2.2.x instance and I can't seem to find any documentation regarding the ability to set the database connection parameters as environmental variables.

I have looked at the documentation on how to [Use environment variables to override configuration settings](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/config-reference-var-name.html) but can't seem to find anything related to this.

Anyone knows if this is possible with a default Magento 2.2.x instance? If so, what are the environmental variables keys that I can use?

Thanks!

Edit: Found a way of doing this thanks to the accepted answer below. Part of app/etc/env.php:

```
...
array (
    'host' => !empty($_SERVER['CONFIG_DB_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['CONFIG_DB_HOST'] : '',
    'dbname' => !empty($_SERVER['CONFIG_DB_DBNAME']) ? $_SERVER['CONFIG_DB_DBNAME'] : '',
    'username' => !empty($_SERVER['CONFIG_DB_USERNAME']) ? $_SERVER['CONFIG_DB_USERNAME'] : '',
    'password' => !empty($_SERVER['CONFIG_DB_PASSWORD']) ? $_SERVER['CONFIG_DB_PASSWORD'] : '',
    'active' => '1',
  ),
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Apache, you can set a $_SERVER variable in the vhost config:

```
SetEnv name "value"
```

This new variable will appear in $_SERVER, not $_ENV. You can access it from Magento's env.php by $_SERVER['name']. You can also define $_ENV variables from index.php:

```
$_ENV['name'] = 'value';
```

There's no pre defined name for database configuration, so you will need to edit app/etc/env.php